# Alignment of Canvas and text in canvas

Tags: canvas, uwp, uwp-xaml

So, I try to center text in a canvas, but I can't figure out how, what I'm currently doing here is this:

```
<Canvas Background="#730D11" Width="138" Height="138" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="S6" Foreground="#EAEAEA" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="45" Canvas.Top="34" />
                    </Canvas>
```

That gets the thing done for `S6`, but if I set that to `S66` for example, it just adds the 6 and keeps it position... I would like to keep the text in the canvas centered all the time.

Also, That canvast is in a `StackPanel` and I want it to be on the right side of that stack panel, but it doesn't go there, how can I fix that? Here is the code I currently use:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Rittensport_Software.CalculatePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Rittensport_Software"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="#E6E6E6">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Background="#073D48" Opacity="0.8"></Canvas>
        <!--Navigation-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image x:Name="mgBackBtn" Source="Assets/Icons/Back.png" Width="96" Height="96" />
            <TextBlock Text="REKENBLAD" Foreground="#F8F8F8" FontSize="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="(Deel 2)" Foreground="#F8F8F8" FontSize="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--There we will put the main shit in (also a grid because it is difficult) -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Top items-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="140,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Text="Klasse" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="35" />
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ClassSelector" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="26,0"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Nummer" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="35" />
                        <ComboBox x:Name="StartNumbers" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="26,0"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Deel" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="35" />
                        <ComboBox x:Name="InputSegment" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="26,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!--The current numer selected-->
                    <Canvas Background="#730D11" Width="138" Height="138" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="S6" Foreground="#EAEAEA" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="45" Canvas.Top="34" />
                    </Canvas>
                </StackPanel>


                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="140,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Piloot:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="35" />
                    <TextBlock Text="NAAM Voornaam" FontSize="35" Margin="10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="(tel)" FontSize="25" Margin="5,9" />

                    <TextBlock Text="Navigator:" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="35" Margin="306,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="NAAM Voornaam" FontSize="35" Margin="10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="(tel)" FontSize="25" Margin="5,9" />
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Border BorderBrush="#707070" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" Margin="70.5,0" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,60,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Gemiste controles" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#0F0F0F" FontSize="35" Margin="140,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBox PlaceholderText="100" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>



 </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Border BorderBrush="#707070" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" Margin="70.5,0" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The result I want to achieve is the following:

[image: result]

But it as to be adaptive to all screens and not static...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to keep the text in the canvas centered all the time

`Canvas` is meant for absolute positioning of child elements using `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties. Values of `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties of its children make no effect on the layout. To position the text in the center use `Grid` instead of `Canvas`:

```
<Grid Background="#730D11" Width="138" Height="138">
    <TextBlock Text="S6" Foreground="#EAEAEA" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

> That canvast is in a StackPanel and I want it to be on the right side of that stack panel, but it doesn't go there

`StackPanel` grows in size only as much as needed to fit all the child elements. Since there's no empty space inside of it, it doesn't make any difference if the child's `HorizontalAlignment` property is set to `Left` or `Right`. To align the content to the right use `Grid` or `RelativePanel`.